# How does shadow-catcher work mathematically?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

I know this workflow: mark object as shadow-catcher, multiply shadow catcher pass with background, alpha-over the image and you are done.

I'm interested in understanding how exactly does the Blender calculate this shadow pass to understand it's strengths and limitations. As far as I know, shadow is just lack of light, so how do you ray-trace it? (Reflections make things even more confusing.)

Here are some confusing properties I've noticed:

- The shadow responds to lights and even lights in HDRs.
- The reflections are included too, they *add* light instead of removing it (which is weird because up until now you were supposed to multiply the shadow pass, but the reflections should be additive IMHO).
- If I put glossy object above glossy shadow catcher, the result is weird. The reflection in shadow-catcher almost looks like the object above was diffuse (it's too bright and white).
- Everything outside of objects shadow and reflection is perfectly white, so directly illuminated parts seem to ignore light strength, angle and color.

So the question is: how exactly the ray-tracing of shadow-catchers work and what's included in the shadow catcher pass? (Is there maybe some equivalent node/material setup that would make things clearer?)